# How to change the item image of the Tab Bar Controller programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I've manually added a Tab Bar Controller from Main file (XCode 14.1). I take it this is the Main storyboard

[image]

Both Item Scenes has their own controller class (custom class).

In either class, I want to change the item image and title. For this question, the image. Inside one of the corresponding scene class (ProfileViewController):

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   
   // Does nothing (both)
  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![1].image = UIImage(named: "square.and.arrow.up.circle")

  self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "square.and.arrow.up.circle")

}
```

I would like to change the image programatically as for one of the tabs, I get the image externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the image incorrectly. To use one of the SF Symbols you need to use:

```
UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.circle")
```

Using `UImage(named:)` tries to load an image from your resource bundle or image assets.